# Solving a transcendental equation of the form : $ \log (y)-a y=b $

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving a physical problem, where I try to solve analytically a transcendental equation of type:

$$ \log (y)-a y=b, $$

here $a$ and $b$ are constants.

The problem is that I get a solution but with an error message who indicate that some solutions may not be found:

```
Solve[Log[y] - a y == b, y]

(* {{y -> -(ProductLog[-a E^b]/a)}} *)
(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. *)
```

Is this the right solution? Please how to found it?

Comment: Note that in Mathematica `Log[y]` is a natural logarithm of `y`. A logarithm with base 10 is `Log10[y]` or `Log[10,y]`

Comment: yes, I know it @roman465. Thank you.

Comment: If you look at the result of `Simplify[Reduce[Log[y] - a y == b, y]]` then you might learn a little more about this. If you know that your constants are Real then you can let `Reduce` and `Simplify` know that and they might do an even better job of helping you understand the results.

Comment: If you plot `Log[y]` and `a+b y` you can see that, depanding on a,b, there exist no, one or two intersections (roots of the equation).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it, but you need to know that

```
ProductLog[z]
```

gives the principal solution for `w` in `z==we^w`. After all use

```
Solve[Log[y] - a y == b, y] // Quiet
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex Trounev, so this solution is sufficient. But how to get all solutions please?

Comment: @Gallagher, to get all solutions, you need to use the other branches of `ProductLog[]`; look up the documentation for this.